# Voltage drops across a series circuit

Tags: series, circuits

How come when I hook up two 10M resistors in series with a input voltage of 12 the two resistors only read 3V each? Should it be closer to 6V each?

Comment: What are you using to measure the voltage? A multimeter has its own resistance, and when you hook it across a 10M resistor you’ve got its resistance in parallel with the 10M.

Answer (score 2):

When you measure such high resistance values, you need to take into consideration the impedance of the Voltmeter you use, as Pete already mentioned.

Normal Multimeters have impedances in the magnitude of 1-5MOhm

[image: Voltage measurement]